# too many specific questions for some topics

Tags: discussion

There seem to be a lot of specific questions being asked and it feels like it's time for some of the major tags to have their own StackExchanges or maybe the weighting of the questions that appear on your homepage and other pages could be changed.

For example, I have javascript as a favourite tag, but the number of javascript questions I see is too damn high.

Comment: I don't follow your logic. There's too many javascript questions... separating them into their own site would decrease(?) the amount!? And therefore that is good?

Comment: My point is that StackOverflow is turning into WebProgrammingOverflow. I think I meant vague/basic rather than specific. OOps, need more coffee...

Comment: [Too damn high.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TUZzK.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

Well, good! That's indication that there is a wealth of knowledge in one place. No need to splinter it, in my opinion. But if you want you're more than welcome to propose a new site on Area51 and see if it flies.

Of course, I don't address the quality of the content. That's going to be a factor whether or not there are separate sites.